# How to get latest Date AND TotalEnrollments from a list with Duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

I have a list of schools. There are duplicated DISTSCH, I need the row that brings me the latest week WITH/AND the corresponding totalenrollmentsEQ.

`select DATACOLLECTIONWEEK, districtname, DISTSCH,totalenrollmentsEQ
from DB.SCHEMA.TEST
where DistrictName like 'District1'
and DISTSCH IN (select DISTSCH
                from DB.SCHEMA.TEST
                where DistrictName like 'District1'
                group by DISTSCH
                having count(*) > 1)`

Comment: Please provide your sample data as tabular text. Also please show us the results that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` to get the most recent record per `distsch`, as determined by ordering column `data_collection_week`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by distsch order by data_collection_week desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Another typical solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.data_collection_week = (
    select max(t1.data_collection_week) from mytable t1 where t1.distsch = t.distsch
)
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, this is exactly what I needed, thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
SELECT MAX(DATACOLLECTIONWEEK)max_week
, districtname
, DISTSCH
,SUM(totalenrollmentsEQ)total
FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST
WHERE DistrictName LIKE 'District1'
AND DISTSCH IN (SELECT DISTSCH
                FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST
                WHERE DistrictName LIKE 'District1'
                GROUP BY DISTSCH
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY districtname
, DISTSCH
```